# Creating a tabbed activity with tab outside navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm working on a project for college, and i would like to create activity which have map on top of screen and below it three tabs and belove that fragment which is displayed on tab click.
Maybe i explained it wrong, I'm sorry in advance.

I searched for tutorials, but all of them had three tabs in action bar, and I don't want that.

Here is the picture with what i had in mind:

[image: diagram]

I'm glad for any kind of help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the numbers from your diagram, make "2" be a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` for your fragments. Make "1" be a `PagerTabStrip`, or the `TabPagerIndicator` from [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), or be [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use LinearLayout in your ContentActivity and inside your map and the Tab control, in the Tab control inside fragment control(you find it in your Designer), or for flexibility FrameLayout.

- LinearLayout(Horizontal)

  - Map
  - TabControl

    - FrameLayout or fragment

documentation for fragment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html